# How to find all MATLAB function blocks in a Simulink model

Tags: matlab, simulink

I would like to know how to find all `MATLAB function` blocks in a Simulink model.
In a model in which I know there are a lot of `MATLAB function` blocks, I tried the following command:

```
find_system(myModel,'LookUnderMasks','on','FollowLinks','on','BlockType','MATLAB Function')
```

However, this command returns an empty cell array. If I try something like this:

```
find_system(myModel,'LookUnderMasks','on','FollowLinks','on','BlockType','Gain')
```

, I'm getting many results. Is the "MATLAB Function" an actual BlockType or is there another term to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to find all MATLAB function blocks.

```
S = sfroot();

% Get block handles
B = find(sfroot, '-isa','Stateflow.EMChart');
```

This will search all open models and returns a list of objects of type Stateflow.EMChart. You can look at the Path property of these objects to reduce the list to the model you want.

Comment: I tried your code, and I'm getting a Stateflow.EMChart object, which is 80x1. I don't have Stateflow, and I'm not sure how to access or view these 80 elements. Also, why use Stateflow for searching the MATLAB Function blocktype?

Comment: MATLAB function block is a special block and is built on top of other technologies which is why you see this. You can index into the 80x1 array like any MATLAB array. Try displaying B(1) and you will be able to see its properties.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define the search depth use the below:

```
h=find_system(myModel,'SearchDepth',N, 'regexp', 'on', 'FollowLinks','on','Findall','on','LookUnderMasks','all',  'BlockType','Gain');
```

Specify N, the higher the N the deeper into the blocks the search will be.

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: MATLAB Function is not a valid argument.

Comment: So what should be the argument for MATLAB Function blocks?